# uncaught typeError:Cannot read property superclass of undefined ExtJs

Tags: extjs, aem

In CQ5, I have created a custom widget for which I have written a javscript. This file is throwing a "uncaught typeError:Cannot read property superclass of undefined" on the line test.SubdomainNewslistingWidget.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);

```
var test = {};

test.SubdomainNewslistingWidget = CQ.Ext.extend(CQ.form.CompositeField, {

    /**
     * @private
     * @type CQ.Ext.form.Hidden
     */
    hiddenField : null,

    headline:null,
    date:null,
    description:null,
    url:null,
    checkbox : null,
    emptyField:null,


    constructor : function(config) {
        config = config || {};
        var defaults = {
            "border" : true
        };
        config = CQ.Util.applyDefaults(config, defaults);
        test.SubdomainNewslistingWidget.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
    },

    // overriding CQ.Ext.Component#initComponent
    initComponent : function() {
        test.SubdomainNewslistingWidget.superclass.initComponent.call(this);

        this.hiddenField = new CQ.Ext.form.Hidden({
            name : this.name
        });
        this.add(this.hiddenField);


        this.headline = new CQ.Ext.form.TextField({
            fieldLabel : "Headline",
            labelStyle : 'display:block;width:85px;',
            width : 600,
            allowBlank : false,
            listeners : {
                change : {
                    scope : this,
                    fn : this.updateHidden
                }
            }
        });
        this.add(this.headline);

        this.date = new CQ.form.DateTime({
            fieldLabel : "Date",
            labelStyle : 'display:block;width:85px;',
            width : 600,
            allowBlank : false,
            editable: false,
            hideTime: true,
            dateFormat: "d F Y",
            listeners : {
                change : {
                    scope : this,
                    fn : this.updateHidden
                }
            }
        });
        this.add(this.date);

        this.description = new CQ.Ext.form.TextArea({
            fieldLabel : "Description",
            labelStyle : 'display:block;width:85px;',
            width : 600,
            allowBlank : false,
            listeners : {
                change : {
                    scope : this,
                    fn : this.updateHidden
                }
            }
        });
        this.add(this.description);


        this.url = new CQ.form.PathField({
            fieldLabel : "URL",
            labelStyle : 'display:block;width:85px;',
            rootPath : "/content/mercer",
            editable : true,
            width : 600,
            allowBlank : false,
            listeners : {
                dialogselect : {
                    scope : this,
                    fn : this.updateHidden
                },
                change : {
                    scope : this,
                    fn : this.updateHidden
                }
            }
        });
        this.add(this.url);

         this.checkbox =  new CQ.form.Selection({
             type:"checkbox",
             fieldLabel:"Link Target",
             options:displayOptionsAnchorTargetSubdomainNewslisting(),
             listeners: {
                 selectionchanged: {
                     scope:this,
                     fn: this.updateHidden
                 }
             },
             optionsProvider: this.optionsProvider
         });

          this.add(this.checkbox);

        /**
         * Added a dummy Empty field to avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception in the resultant array
         * Without this hidden field, the empty values will be not be added to the multifield list
         */
        this.emptyField = new CQ.Ext.form.TextField({
            fieldLabel: "Empty Field",
            width:200,
            maxLength: "30",
            defaultValue: "empty",
            hidden:true,
            value:"empty",
        });
        this.add(this.emptyField);

    },

    // overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#setValue
    setValue : function(value) {

        var parts = value.split(/<#-@>/);
        console.log("displayOptionsAnchorTargetSubdomainNewslisting#parts", parts);
        this.headline.setValue(parts[0]);
        this.date.setValue(parts[1]);
        this.description.setValue(parts[2]);
        this.url.setValue(parts[3]);
        this.checkbox.setValue(parts[4]);
        this.emptyField.setValue(parts[5]);


        this.hiddenField.setRawValue(value);

    },

    // overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#getValue
    getValue : function() {
        return this.getRawValue();
    },

    // overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#getRawValue
    getRawValue : function() {
        return this.headline.getValue() + "<#-@>"
                + this.date.getValue() + "<#-@>"
                + this.description.getValue() + "<#-@>"
                + this.url.getValue() + "<#-@>"
                + this.checkbox.getValue() + "<#-@>"
                + this.emptyField.getValue();
    },

    // private
    updateHidden : function() {
        this.hiddenField.setValue(this.getValue());
    }

});

function displayOptionsAnchorTargetSubdomainNewslisting()
{
    return [{
        "text":"check to open link in new tab",
        "value":true

    }]
}

// register xtype
test.SubdomainNewslistingWidget.XTYPE = "subdomainNewslisting";
CQ.Ext.reg(test.SubdomainNewslistingWidget.XTYPE, test.SubdomainNewslistingWidget);
```

I am not able to locate what the problem is. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure with the error? It works fine for me. Any particular browse you are facing this issue with? What version of CQ and browser are you using?

Comment: The error says test.SubdomainNewslistingWidget is undefined, so it Cannot read property superclass, well the code looks correct though. I usually do this by CQ.Ext.namespace('ProjectName.widget'); ProjectName.widget.SubdomainNewslistingWidget = CQ.Ext.extend(CQ.form.CompositeField, { later use the same for superclass constructor using ProjectName.widget.SubdomainNewslistingWidget.superclass.constructor.call(this, <arguments>). Alternatively can you try this out.